# Designing registration page with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i'm new to bootstrap ,,i'm not good at designing,,

trying to design registration page

registration.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">

    <title>Signin Template for Bootstrap</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="css/registration.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Just for debugging purposes. Don't actually copy these 2 lines! -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="../../assets/js/ie8-responsive-file-warning.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <script src="../../assets/js/ie-emulation-modes-warning.js"></script>

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="container">

      <form class="form-signin">
        <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please Register</h2>
        <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Email address</label>
        <input type="email" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required autofocus>
        <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
        <input type="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Remember me
          </label>
        </div>

        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
      </form>

    </div> <!-- /container -->


    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
    <script src="../../assets/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

i need to add input form for the username

like the input form in this design

i tried this code

```
<span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">@</span>
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
```

but it isn't like the input form ,that in the design

Answer (score 0):

May this helps.

```
<div class="input-group">
   <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">@</span>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are trying to use one of the Bootstrap examples:

http://getbootstrap.com/examples/signin/

And adding your code to it:

```
<span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">@</span>
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
```

However, please note that the Bootstrap example has relative links to the resources, like:

```
<link href="../../dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

So assuming you have a different server setup, make sure your code points to where your resources really are relative to the page you are loading.

Also, use something like the Developer Tools on Google Chrome to see if everything is loading correctly and you don't get any 404's.

Hope this helps.